# ScalaJson has no integer type?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am trying to write a JSON API using Scala & Play Framework. My application needs to respond to a request in JSON format, converting a list of products to JSON

I'm implementing a `writes` method on my Product class which converts the fields to JSON. Every value needs to be converted to js using a method like `JsString`

Here 'tis

```
  def writes(product: Product) = {
    JsObject(Seq(
      "id" -> JsNumber(product.id),
      "title" -> JsString(product.title),
      "description" -> JsString(product.description),
      "available_online" -> JsBoolean(product.available_online)
    ))
  }
```

This code is failing in the third line because of a type mismatch

```
[error]  found   : Integer
[error]  required: BigDecimal
```

But when I consult [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.package), there seems to be no type for an integer.

So how should I deal with a field like `id` in JSON ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON does not distinguish between integer and floating point types, that's why you only see the `JsNumber(value: BigDecimal)` method in the documentation. You would have to convert your `Integer` to `BigDecimal` first using the [`BigDecimal`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.BigDecimal$) object:

```
def writes(product: Product) = {
  JsObject(Seq(
    "id" -> JsNumber(BigDecimal(product.id)),
    "title" -> JsString(product.title),
    "description" -> JsString(product.description),
    "available_online" -> JsBoolean(product.available_online)
  ))
}
```